# Como exibir o indice do conteudo de um objeto no PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Tenho o seguinte conteudo em meu objeto:

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'indicadorContinuidade' => string 'S' (length=1)
  public 'quantidadeRegistros' => int 300
  public 'proximoIndice' => int 300
  public 'boletos' => 
    array (size=300)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'numeroBoletoBB' => string '00019221249999000149' (length=20)
          public 'dataRegistro' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'dataVencimento' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'valorOriginal' => int 1700
          public 'carteiraConvenio' => int 17
          public 'variacaoCarteiraConvenio' => int 19
          public 'codigoEstadoTituloCobranca' => int 2
          public 'estadoTituloCobranca' => string 'Mvto. Cartorio' (length=14)
          public 'contrato' => int 0
          public 'dataMovimento' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'dataCredito' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'valorAtual' => int 0
          public 'valorPago' => int 0
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'numeroBoletoBB' => string '00019221249999000150' (length=20)
          public 'dataRegistro' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'dataVencimento' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'valorOriginal' => int 1800
          public 'carteiraConvenio' => int 17
          public 'variacaoCarteiraConvenio' => int 19
          public 'codigoEstadoTituloCobranca' => int 2
          public 'estadoTituloCobranca' => string 'Mvto. Cartorio' (length=14)
          public 'contrato' => int 0
          public 'dataMovimento' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'dataCredito' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'valorAtual' => int 0
          public 'valorPago' => int 0
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'numeroBoletoBB' => string '00019221249999000151' (length=20)
          public 'dataRegistro' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'dataVencimento' => string '09.04.2019' (length=10)
          public 'valorOriginal' => int 1900
          public 'carteiraConvenio' => int 17
          public 'variacaoCarteiraConvenio' => int 19
          public 'codigoEstadoTituloCobranca' => int 2
          public 'estadoTituloCobranca' => string 'Mvto. Cartorio' (length=14)
          public 'contrato' => int 0
          public 'dataMovimento' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'dataCredito' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'valorAtual' => int 0
          public 'valorPago' => int 0
```

eu queria exibir em uma lista o conteudo deste objeto (isso eu consegui), acompanhado pelo numero do índice de cada um (isso eu não consegui).
Como faço para extrair o indice de cada "boleto"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boa noite, não sei se entendi direito a questão, mas acredito q vc tenha usado o foreach para listar então daria pra fazer:

```
foreach($obj->boletos as $key => $value)
```

onde $key é o indice e $value é o objeto boleto.

Como disse não sei se entendi a dúvida, mas espero ter ajudado

Comment: Deu certinho! Obrigado!